# GitHub Repo Out of Sync with Local Repo

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a GitHub repository that is out-of-sync with my local repo. `git log origin/master` lists commits on 2022-08-07, 2022-10-19 (2), and 2022-11-14.

However, the 2022-11-14 commit is NOT appearing on Github, even though it appeared to sync properly in VS Code.

I think what happened is that I created a custom URL (CNAME file) on 2022-11-01, which created 5 commits (I had problems getting the URL setup and followed the GitHub Doc which recommended deleting/creating it until it worked).

I forgot to pull the 2022-11-01 commits before making the 2022-11-14 commit and sync.

I've tried answers from numerous stackoverflow posts (most suggesting some kind of pull/push), but nothing has worked (usually responds with 'Already up to date' or 'Everything up-to-date'. I'm not a git guru. Please help...

UPDATE: This may not be an elongate solution, but it worked:

1. Made a backup copy of the local repo
2. Cloned the remote repo to a new folder
3. Using WinMerge, updated the clone repo from the backup copy of the local repo to restore all changes made since 2022-10-19
4. Committed and Sync'd clone to remote
5. Deleted contents of local repo
6. Copied contents of cloned repo to local repo
7. Deleted cloned repo.

N.B. What has happened to stackoverflow??? Less than one hour after posting this question, it has two votes to close, with no explanation. This used to be a helpful forum...

Comment: What's the output of `git branch` and `git stats`? Have you tried `git push`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a force push might have overridden the history on GitHub side, while your remote tracking branch `origin/master` remained unchanged.

Check if said remote tracking branch (in your old local repository) is associated with, using `git branch -avv`

Check your [`git reflog` content](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) for any reference to the missing commit SHA1.